# Python for loop list of strings different output

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

**Why is this codes output different?**

```
lst = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6", "id7", "id8"]

for i in lst:
    print(i[2])
    
print([i[2] for i in lst])
```

Comment: First is an iteration, where you print every index 2 of every string. The second is a list comprehension, where you create a new list with the same data as above and prints the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is an iteration, where you print every index 2 of every string. The second is a list comprehension, where you create a new list with the same data as above and prints the list.

First:

```
lst = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6", "id7", "id8"]

for i in lst:
    print(i[2])
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Second:

```
print([i[2] for i in lst])
```

Result:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

If you want the first version to imitate the same result as the second out, simply create a list and append to it:

```
newlst = []

for i in lst:
    newlst.append(i[2])
print(newlst)
```

Result:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

If you want to print the list comprehension in one line, like the for loop, then use:

```
[print(i[2]) for i in lst]
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

If you need a type string for the comprehension, you could do this:

```
s = "\n".join([i[2] for i in lst])

print(s)
print(type(s))
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: What about the first result with a code like print([i[2] for i in lst]) ?

Comment: @mvp I'm sorry, I do not understand what you are asking. What would you like with the code `print([i[2] for i in lst])`? :-)

Comment: Just wondering if there was a way to get this output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and so on with one line of code :)

Comment: @mvp Added example. :-)

Comment: Is there a way to change the type of [print(i[2]) for i in lst] from list to string? :)

Comment: @mvp you mean saving the print output as a string?

Comment: Yes, when i print the type of both ways, one is list and the other is string.

Comment: @mvp Added too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are doing multiple prints. In the second case you are building a list with all the data, then this said list is printed

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6", "id7", "id8"]
# You are iterating over the list
for i in lst:
    # prints 3rd character in each element (i)
    print(i[2]) # be default this statement has newline at end
    # To print with spaces try print(i[2], end=' ')

# here you are doing it using list comprehension so the output will be in a list    
print([i[2] for i in lst])
```